# Python "parser" not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create a Hexviewer in Python (3), while coding, I issued an error that I couldn't fix, I am trying to make a function, that gets in a "\n" every [fontsize]/500, but it is just making "\n"s all over the place, what did I do wrong?
(Python 3.4.3)

```
def parse(parse0):
    parse0 = list(parse0)
    i = 0
    for cur in parse0:
        if not cur == 10:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = 0
        if i > 500/fontsize:
            parse0.insert(parse0.index(cur),10)
            i = 0
    return parse0
```

Comment: I am not understanding quite well what you are trying to do... Are you trying to add an `\n` or a `10`, because in your script you are inserting the number 10. What are the `\n`s for?

Comment: 10 is the decimal number of "\n"

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify the list during iteration on its elements.

Make a new empty list and insert there your elements (and `\n`'s) one by one in your loop)